# C# : Path of an USB key

Tags: c#, path, save, usb

I created a small program to back up data to a txt, only the final goal would be to save the txt on a USB key.

This USB key will contain the software and txt.
My only question is how to know the way, imagining that it can have several USB key connected to the computer?

Code:

```
   string path = System.IO.Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Tableau.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name your USB to something like 'BAKUP-USB' like I did in this example you can search for it amoung all connected devices. And after that you can get the path to the USB that you want.

Hope this gives you atleast something.

```
DriveInfo[] mydrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo mydrive in mydrives)
{
    //Check for removable devices like USB's
    if (mydrive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable) 
    {
        //Check for that specific USB
        if (mydrive.VolumeLabel.Equals("BAKUP-USB")) 
        {
            DirectoryInfo path = mydrive.RootDirectory;
            Path.GetFullPath(path.ToString());
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I succeeded thanks to you, you saved my life :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save to your project folder (no matter where that is), use "C:" with no backslash.

```
  using(TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:MyText.txt")){
     tr.ReadAllLines();
  }
```

will read the file "MyText.txt" from your project folder whether it is in c:\Documents\Visual Studio.... or x:\USB\MyProgram..."